# How to transform nested xml table to flat table with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file

```
<xml>
  <order>
    <orderid>123</orderid>
    <orderdate>2013-04-12T00:00:00.000+01:00</orderdate>
    <orderline>
      <articlename>AAAA</articlename>
      <quantity>10</quantity>
    </orderline>
    <orderline>
      <articlename>BBBB</articlename>
      <quantity>15</quantity>
    </orderline>
  </order>
  <order>
    ...
    </order>
</xml>
```

And i need to transform it using XSLT to:

```
<xml>
  <item>
    <orderid>123</orderid>
    <articlename>AAAA</articlename>
    <quantity>10</quantity>
  </item>
  <item>
    <orderid>123</orderid>
    <articlename>BBBB</articlename>
    <quantity>15</quantity>
  </item>
</xml>
```

I already tried some transformations using `<xsl:call-template>` and `<xsl:apply-templates>`, but nothing worked for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the XSLT you've tried already.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl I can't, because I didn't save all the versions I tried and my last tried version is similar to Sundar G version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple stylesheet should do it:

#### Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--
  Identity transform:
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT 
  -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="orderline">
    <item>
      <!--
      Apply preceding <orderid> sibling and the children of the current element
      -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::orderid | node()"/>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="order">
    <!--
    Only apply <orderline> children, <orderdate> is dropped and <orderid> is
    handled by the template above
    -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="orderline"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Input

```
<xml>
  <order>
    <orderid>123</orderid>
    <orderdate>2013-04-12T00:00:00.000+01:00</orderdate>
    <orderline>
      <articlename>AAAA</articlename>
      <quantity>10</quantity>
    </orderline>
    <orderline>
      <articlename>BBBB</articlename>
      <quantity>15</quantity>
    </orderline>
  </order>

  <!-- Added additional <order> element for demonstration -->
  <order>
    <orderid>456</orderid>
    <orderdate>2014-05-13T00:00:00.000+02:00</orderdate>
    <orderline>
      <articlename>CCCC</articlename>
      <quantity>20</quantity>
    </orderline>
    <orderline>
      <articlename>DDDD</articlename>
      <quantity>25</quantity>
    </orderline>
  </order>
</xml>
```

#### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
  <item>
    <orderid>123</orderid>
    <articlename>AAAA</articlename>
    <quantity>10</quantity>
  </item>
  <item>
    <orderid>123</orderid>
    <articlename>BBBB</articlename>
    <quantity>15</quantity>
  </item>
  <item>
    <orderid>456</orderid>
    <articlename>CCCC</articlename>
    <quantity>20</quantity>
  </item>
  <item>
    <orderid>456</orderid>
    <articlename>DDDD</articlename>
    <quantity>25</quantity>
  </item>
</xml>
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Nothing special about this solution -- it's basic XSLT. Check out e.g. [this SO answer by @dimitre-novatchev](http://stackoverflow.com/a/341589/825783) for a good list of resources on learning XSLT.

Comment: The question to the (great!) answer by @dimitre-novatchev got deleted. But the answer is also available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858345/xsltwhich-is-the-best-tutorial-you-would-like-to-recommend/2306680#2306680

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers: Thanks! Unfortunately, though, the question you linked also got deleted.

Comment: I copy/pasted the HTML here: http://pastebin.com/5ipQtRE2 can you try saving that as a local file, then open it? (they also deleted my meta question about this, so I cannot find other references right now). You might also want to watch this account: http://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev 

Later I also found this: https://www.google.com/search?q="Some+tutorials+by+Norman+Walsh%3A"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xml>
         <xsl:for-each select="//order/orderline">
        <item>
           <orderid><xsl:value-of select="//orderid" /></orderid>
             <articlename><xsl:value-of select="articlename" /></articlename>
             <quantity><xsl:value-of select="quantity" /></quantity> 
         </item>
            </xsl:for-each>

  </xml>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: 1. for-each and item ending tags are in wrong order.
2. I already try this and it won't work. For me it looks like there is something with select="//order/orderline" in for-each.

Comment: Retyped all from 'blank sheet' and it worked, but there is one problem: in file there is several orders and all lines get the orderid from first one.